# CTFont and Core Text framework

Tags: iphone, ios, core-text

I'm trying to use CTFont in an iPhone app.  I have :-

1. Added the Core Text framework
2. Added #import "CoreText/CoreText." to the file I am trying to use CTFont in.

However the compiler is saying that "CTFont undeclared"

??? what am I missing?

Answer (score 16):

You should #import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

Answer (score 1):

Also, just incase your still having issues. CTFontRef is the struct you want not CTFont